# Metatrader 5 login() broken after update?

Tags: python, metatrader5

We developed some moths ago a bunch of python scripts that use [Metatrader 5](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5) library (5.0.34).

Since client's update 5.00 (the lib requires a running client), previously working login() function seems broken:

```
SEVERE LOGIN FAIL error code: (-2, 'Terminal: Invalid params')
```

Previously-called `mt5.initialize(login,password,server)` function still seems to be working, it doesn't raise any exception. Current client version is 5.00 build 3033. The client itself is working

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With new mt5 version, "server" has become mandatory.

Specyfying it in both initialize() and login() calls, made it.

Comment: This worked for me, but their docs (https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/python_metatrader5/mt5login_py) don't use the server as argument. Did they forget to update their documentation?

By the way I only needed to specify it in the login, not in the initialize.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just simply specify the user, password, and server all at login time.